# Android app crashes if I press the back button after a change in screen orientation (only using real device, not virtual)

Tags: android, orientation

I have a basic android app with 4 activities directly under the main activity.  I start one of those activities using a button click from the main activity.  If I change the screen orientation on one of those sub-activities and then press the back button, it fails to bring me back to the main activity, and it crashes.  This issue does not occur if I avoid changing the screen orientation.  Strangely, if I am using a virtual device this does not occur.  If I am using my real device (Samsung galaxy note 3) this occurs consistently.  I have the logcat here, and will post code if might be considered helpful.

```
03-30 14:58:03.912    5203-5203/vanwert.sdb E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 14464888-byte allocation.
03-30 14:58:03.922    5203-5203/vanwert.sdb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vanwert.sdb/vanwert.sdb.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2294)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3872)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at vanwert.sdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3872)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at vanwert.sdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3872)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3563)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:475)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at vanwert.sdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2348)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3872)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: You probably have to recycle your Bitmaps before the Activity gets recreated

Comment: Also make sure you are not keeping a reference to the context. Keeping a reference to the context can prevent the garbage collector from freeing memory when the orientation is changed.

Comment: I've been reading up on this, and I'm still confused.  My drawables are designated in my XML files, and I would like to make sure there is no memory leak associated with them.  Like I mentioned, I have no issues with crashing until I change the screen orientation and then go back to the main activity.  I've read many posts on this and I still cant get to the bottom of it.